# HTML: disable dynamically added <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I never thought to ask this, but I work on a security product and so we implement pretty strict protection against XSS:

- We disallow `<` and `>` in user input both server- and client-side
- If the user does manage to make a request containing either of those characters, the server will disable their account and leave a warning for an admin
- Angular also sanitizes interpolated content before injecting it into the DOM

This is all great and dandy, except, it hurts UX and it's bad for performance. Surely, SURELY, there is a way to just tell the browser NOT to execute `<script>` tags added after initial document parsing, right? We use a modern bundled workflow and any lazy-loading of JavaScript will be done via `import("/some/js/module")` calls which get rebased by the bundler but will never be fed a dynamic value at runtime.

Even if there isn't a way to straight up tell the browser not to run dynamically added (by JS after page load) `<script>` tags, is there a tried and true workflow for rendering, say, markdown + HTML subset user-produced content in iframes? I am familiar with iframes at a high-level, but I mean can the parent document/page manipulate the DOM content of the iframe or something so even if it does add a `<script>` tag inside the iframe, the script code will not have access to the parent document's JS environment?

> Actually that would be cool as a sandboxed way to display user content because they could intentionally include a script and make a little interactive widget for other users to mess with, in theory (maybe an antifeature in practice).

Comment: what about dompurify? that's exactly what it is made for or am i missing some point? 
see: https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

Comment: There is `<iframe sandbox>` and [HTTP CSP headers to restrict things like `<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Comment: https://web.dev/sanitizer/ Also look out for `TrustedTypes` and `Content-Security-Policy`.

Comment: @Andy Neat library but I explicitly said I want a "flat-out block all scripts unless I specially allow one" approach supported by the browser. No perf impact and fewer chances to screw up.

Comment: @connexo Sanitizer doesn't seem to be supported at all yet. Also I'm very weary of new APIs being aggressively pushed by Google. Don't want to be a Chrome lackey. :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with CSP (Content Security Policy)

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp#inline-code-considered-harmful

Example:
Allow only :

```
<script nonce="EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa">
  // Some inline code I can't remove yet, but need to asap.
</script>
```

with

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa'
```

Start by blocking all with:

```
default-src 'none'
```

Comment: To add to this, do *not* add `unsafe-eval` or `unsafe-inline` to that header. Do your research on the Content-Security-Policy header and make sure you use safe values.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for. Block by default, allow on case-by-case basis afterwards is perfect!